# android how to convert decimal to int(going to be calculated) then to decimal(the result) again

Tags: android

i am developing an app about pmt. Here i have a function which will convert the input in an edittext(number only) into decimal (it was requested that the edittext will somehow make the given input from the user looks like a currency, Example the user is typing three number "987" in edittext it will show "987" no change but when the user type more, one or more lets say "987654" it will be "987,654")

```
Edittext 1st example
987
Edittext 2nd example
987,654
Edittext another example
987,654,321
Edittext another example
9,876
Edittext another example
98,765
```

however this function will make the input from that edittext not calculate-able(i am still new with android(eclipse)i have another function that will get the input from the same edittext and calculate automatically(without a button click or some action) then display the result on a textview on the same layout)
I am wondering if we, lets say convert it to int(to calculate) then convert it back to decimal. Or somehow store the the data for temporary to be calculated, without changing the display, the display on the edittext would still be decimal format.

my makedecimal function:

```
public void myEditTextAndroidOnClick(View v)
                {
                                MyEditText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

                                DigitsKeyListener dkl = new DigitsKeyListener(true,true);
                                MyEditText.setKeyListener(dkl);

                                MyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                        private String current = "";

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                String userInput=s.toString();

                                if(!userInput.toString().equals(current)){
                                                MyEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                                                String cleanString = userInput.replaceAll("[,]", "");

                                                if(cleanString.length()>0){
                                                                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);                                                
                                                                String formated = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance().format(parsed);

                                                                current = formated;
                                                                MyEditText.setText(formated);
                                                                MyEditText.setSelection(formated.length());
                                                }else{
                                                                MyEditText.setText(cleanString);
                                                                MyEditText.setSelection(cleanString.length());
                                                }

                                                MyEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                int count, int after) {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                int before, int count) {
                        }
                    });                                                           
               }
```

the calculator

```
MyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    String text1 = MyEditText.getText().toString();
                    if (text1.length() != 0) {
                        int input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);

                        int input2 = Integer.valueOf(s.toString());

                        int output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                        MyTextViewThatWillDisplayTheResult.setText(output + "");
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }
            });
            }
```

the text2 comes from another edittext on the same layout.I am thinking If this function could merge in the same function or somehow convert into int(i use long actually)then convert back to decimal on the MyTextViewThatWillDisplayTheResult. But i don't know how to do that, i am stuck at here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

While showing your data in *edittext* put comma and when calculating, remove commas and then do calculation.

use replace:

```
x=x.replaceAll(',', "");
```